# To build Rcpp package, how to call my R function (not from R package) in my Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package

I am trying to build a Rcpp package. In my Rcpp function, I am trying to call the R function written by myself (not from any package, for here **sum_matrix_row** for example) in my Rcpp function. For that R function, I have put it in the /package/R/ folder.

To make it simple, I will give an easy example here, my R function:

```
sum_matrix_row <- function(x) {return(matrix(apply(x, 1, sum), ncol = 1))}
```

And my Rcpp function (called test_function), I put it in the /package/src/ folder:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;

Function sum_matrix_row = Environment::global_env()["sum_matrix_row"];

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List asmbPLS_fit_rcpp(arma::mat test_matrix) {
  
  aram::colvec matrix_row = sum_matrix_row(test_matrix)
  
  List output = List::create(_["matrix_row"] = matrix_row);

  return (output);
}
```

This one always works when I load **sum_matrix_row** function first and then sourceCpp my Rcpp function, but this cannot work when I build the Rcpp package. Does anyone have some suggestions on that? Thanks a lot!

---

**Edit April 20 2022** to provide more details on my question

```
packagetest
├── DESCRIPTION 
├── NAMESPACE  
├── man
│    ├── rcpparma_hello_world.Rd  
│    └── packagetest-package.Rd  
├── R
│    ├── sum_matrix_row.R   
│    └── RcppExports.R  
└── src 
     ├── Makevars  
     ├── Makevars.win  
     ├── rcpparma_hello_world.cpp   
     ├── RcppExports.cpp  
     ├── RcppExports.o   
     └── test_function.cpp
```

The codes I used to create these files are:

```
RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("packagetest")
setwd("~/Rpackage/packagetest")
Rcpp::compileAttributes()
devtools::document()
```

And in my Rcpp function, I have changed my codes to:

```
Function sum_matrix_row = Environment::namespace_env(packagetest)["sum_matrix_row"]
```

to call my R function.

Then I got the errors like:

```
test_function.cpp:5:54: error: 'packagetest' was not declared in this scope
    Function sum_matrix_row = Environment::namespace_env(packagetest)["sum_matrix_row"];
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
   test_function.cpp:5:54: note: suggested alternative: 'clock_getres'
    Function sum_matrix_row = Environment::namespace_env(packagetest)["sum_matrix_row"];
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                                         clock_getres
   test_function.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::List asmbPLS_fit_rcpp(arma::mat)':
   test_function.cpp:10:3: error: 'aram' has not been declared
      aram::colvec matrix_row = sum_matrix_row(test_matrix);
      ^~~~
   test_function.cpp:12:48: error: 'matrix_row' was not declared in this scope
      List output = List::create(_["matrix_row"] = matrix_row);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
   test_function.cpp:12:48: note: suggested alternative: 'sum_matrix_row'
      List output = List::create(_["matrix_row"] = matrix_row);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                   sum_matrix_row
   make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:245: test_function.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'packagetest'
```

Does anyone have any ideas on these?

---

**Edit April 20 2022** according to @user20650 's suggestion:
My updated codes for my rcpp function, I add quote for packagetest, and add a convert function as<>:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

Rcpp::Function sum_matrix_row = Environment::namespace_env("packagetest")["sum_matrix_row"];

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List asmbPLS_fit_rcpp(arma::mat test_matrix) {
  
  aram::colvec matrix_row = as<aram::colvec>(sum_matrix_row(test_matrix));
  
  List output = List::create(_["matrix_row"] = matrix_row);
  
  return (output);
}
```

After this, I still get some errors:

```
test_function.cpp: In function 'Rcpp::List asmbPLS_fit_rcpp(arma::mat)':
   test_function.cpp:11:3: error: 'aram' has not been declared
      aram::colvec matrix_row = as<aram::colvec>(sum_matrix_row(test_matrix));
      ^~~~
   test_function.cpp:13:48: error: 'matrix_row' was not declared in this scope
      List output = List::create(_["matrix_row"] = matrix_row);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
   test_function.cpp:13:48: note: suggested alternative: 'sum_matrix_row'
      List output = List::create(_["matrix_row"] = matrix_row);
                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~
                                                   sum_matrix_row
   make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:245: test_function.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package 'packagetest'
```

**I found that I write aram instead of arma, now it's fixed!**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and Rcpp.  As you already build a package to work with Rcpp, why don't you just stick the helper function to the same package?  That way it ends up in the same namespace and you should be able to call it via `Rcpp::Function()` (whether or not is a good idea is another question...).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, I have put that R function I need to call in the /package/R/ folder, and I try to use Function sum_matrix_row = Environment::global_env()["sum_matrix_row"] to call the R function, but there is some error, I think the way I define the Rcpp::Function might not be right, do you have a suggestion on this part?

Comment: I think the point was not to try to load the R function from the global env but from the package. /try replacing the relevant line with `Environment pkg = Environment::namespace_env("packagetest"); Function sum_matrix_row = pkg["sum_matrix_row"];`; (there may be a neater way to do this but this should work). You will also need to deal with the line `arma::colvec matrix_row = ...` as you need to convert a SEXP to an arma object - it doesn't happen automatically here.

Comment: ... ah just noticed this line in your question:`Environment::namespace_env(packagetest)` -- you need quotes

Comment: Hi @user20650, thank you very much for your help! I have edited my codes according to your suggestion, but there are still some errors, I will update the results in my question. Could you please provide more suggestions on that? Thanks!

Comment: Try arma:: instead of aram::?

Comment: @lmeninato genius, man..... It's fixed now!